# Effect on Impurities on Young's Modulus

Tags: material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

What effect does addition of Impurities have on Young's Modulus of a material? Does the Youn's Modulus Always increase or Always decrease or depends on the Additive? What is the intuitive explanation for the same?

Comment: Impurities (or 'dopants') alter the microcrystalline structure of metals, affecting the *macroscopic* ('bulk') properties of the metal. Search for 'alloys'.

Comment: Carbon in iron, to make steel, increases it. Gallium in aluminum, well, that has a rather drastic negative impact. No intuitive explanation is possible, even as a materials scientist.